# Create a local settings file using poetry

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I have a python script that checks some files in a certain directory that uses a settings.ini file with local settings to a database and where the rootdir of the files to check is located on your environment and some git settings.

This file was now on the same directory as the script.
In the code I used the following command to access this:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')
```

Now I want to change my script to a Poetry project.
I want to change the layout to:

```
my-Package
|
|-- Source dir
|      |- script.py
|-- Settings dir
|      |- settings.ini
|-- pyproject.toml
```

What is the best way to find my settings.ini in my code?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `settings.ini` contains secrets like passwords, credentials, API keys and such, it is not safe to store it with the project itself. If your project history or version control accidentally leaks to public, any automated credential scraper bot will immediately attack your server.

A better place to store settings is the user home directory, and a subdirectory there.

- On UNIX you get [.config directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33945/14115). This directory is shared by all applications on your operating system.
- Not sure what's the equivalent on Windows

You can get a file in this directory as:

```py
import os

config_file_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/my-app-config.ini")
```

Comment: I am on windows, I can of course find an equivalent, but I don't think this is the right place, because then when I make a new version and for example I need a new setting, (for example log_level=1 ) which probably don't have to be changed by the users they don't have the new line because it isn't changed when they use 'poetry update'

Comment: A good point. You can usually split your settings to multiple files, secret and "public" which are part of the application itself. In this case the file must be within your Python module directory and you can get a settings file that is in the same directory as the current Python module like this:

`settings_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "public-settings.ini")`